# Need help scraping a loose piece of text from webpage without div using bs4/python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning python since last week and i need to **scrape** info about cities on a website. I manage to crawl the whole site but i can't quite **scrape** the specific text info i need in each city webpage (here's the url of one of the cities info (http://www.mon-maire.fr/maire-de-abbecourt-02))

here's the block i'm working from

```
<div class="constructeur">
<b>Village: </b>Abbécourt <br/>
<b>Population :</b> 536 habitants <br/>
<b>Département :</b> Aisne <br/>
<b>Code postal :</b> 02300 <br/>
</div>
```

i'm trying to create a list like this whith the loose text in it

`list = [Abbécourt,536 habitants,Aisne,02300]`

I came up with this code

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'http://www.mon-maire.fr/maire-de-abbecourt-02' 
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

sidebar = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"constructeur"})
for li in sidebar:
    b = li.findAll('br')
    print(b)
```

but it prints only `[<br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>]`

When looking into bs4 doc, i tried

```
b = li.findAll('br.next_element')
b = li.findAll('br.previous_element')
```

but it doesn't work. I'm still looking into the bs4 doc for a solution but in the meantime, if someone would be kind enough to help me, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

```py
b = [i.next_sibling.strip() for i in page_soup.select('div.constructeur > b')]
```

Rather than find the parent element just find the sub-elements you actually care about, that is done using bs4's CSS selectors (`.select`), what the string, `'div.constructeur > b'`, says is grab all bold tags which are within a div element with class constructeur, this returns a list.

Iterate over that list of b tags using list comprehension, grab the `next_sibling` to the b tags which will be the data you want, strip the text since it has a bunch of whitespace.

---

The reason why `li.findAll('br.next_element')` doesn't work is because that function operates on a tag object which is what is contained in the list returned by `.findAll`.

What you want is

```py
b = li.findAll('br')
b = [i.previous_element.strip() for i in b]
```